# operator>> and << output being nulled when outputted

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bit-shift

i dont understand why the output of both functions are getting nulled when i output them:

```
class uint128_t{

private:
    uint64_t UPPER, LOWER;

public:
    // constructors
    uint128_t(){
        UPPER = 0;
        LOWER = 0;
    }

    template <typename T>
    uint128_t(T rhs){
        UPPER = 0;
        LOWER = (uint64_t) rhs;
    }

    template <typename S, typename T>
    uint128_t(const S upper_rhs, const T lower_rhs){
        UPPER = (uint64_t) upper_rhs;
        LOWER = (uint64_t) lower_rhs;
    }

    uint128_t(const uint128_t & rhs){
        UPPER = rhs.UPPER;
        LOWER = rhs.LOWER;
    }

    //  RHS input args only

    // assignment operator
    template <typename T> uint128_t & operator=(T rhs){
        UPPER = 0;
        LOWER = (uint64_t) rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    uint128_t & operator=(uint128_t & rhs){
        UPPER = rhs.UPPER;
        LOWER = rhs.LOWER;
        return *this;
    }


    uint128_t operator<<(int shift){
        if (shift >= 128)
            return uint128_t(0, 0);
        else if (shift == 64)
            return uint128_t(LOWER, 0);
        else if (shift < 64)
            return uint128_t((UPPER << shift) + (LOWER >> (64 - shift)), LOWER << shift);
        else if ((128 > shift) && (shift > 64)){
            uint128_t a =uint128_t(LOWER << (shift - 64), 0);
            // a will show the correct values 
            std::cout << a.upper() << " " << a.lower() << std::endl;
            return uint128_t(LOWER << (shift - 64), 0);
            // in the program that includes this, printing out the values show 0 0
        }
    }

    uint128_t operator>>(int shift){
        if (shift >= 128)
            return uint128_t(0, 0);
        else if (shift == 64)
            return uint128_t(0, UPPER);
        else if (shift <= 64)
            return uint128_t(UPPER >> shift , ((UPPER << (64 - shift))) + (LOWER >> shift));
        else if ((128 > shift) && (shift > 64))
            return uint128_t(0, (UPPER >> (shift - 64)));
    }

    uint128_t operator<<=(int shift){
        *this = *this << shift;
        return *this;
    }

    uint128_t operator>>=(int shift){
        *this = *this >> shift;
        return *this;
    }

    const uint64_t upper() const {
        return UPPER;
    }

    const uint64_t lower() const {
        return LOWER;
    }

// lots of other stuff

};

int main(){

    uint128_t a(0x123456789abcdef1ULL, 0x123456789abcdef1ULL);

    a>>= 127; // or a <<= 127;
    std::cout <<a.upper() << " " <<a.lower() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/jnZI9

can anyone figure out why?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: me and debuggers dont mix. i debug with `cout`, as shown in the code

Comment: You should not accept that. Learn to use debuggers. It will safe you countless hours of your life. (also, your `cout`-skills seem to be insufficient to solve this problem).

Comment: "me and debuggers dont mix" Well, get over it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your int is 128 bits, you are shifting it down (right) 127 bits which means the upper most bit will be moved to the lower most position, and all other bits will be 0.

But the int in your example is `0x1....`, `0x1` (the highest nibble) is `0001` in binary, which does not have the upper bit set.  So 0 is the correct output.

If you change the `0x1...` to an `0x8...` (or anything higher than 0x7) you will most likely see 0...1 in the output.

Answer (score 2):

`>> 127` means shift-out the right-most 127 bits in the number. Since your uint128_t is 0x1234...., the most significant bit is '0'. After `a >>= 127`, the number becomes 0, so the output is `0 0` as expected.

---

As for `<<=`, this is because

```
uint128_t & operator=(uint128_t & rhs)
```

doesn't match for an rvalue `rhs`, while

```
template <typename T> uint128_t & operator=(T rhs)
```

matches when `T == uint128_t` also, so in

```
    *this = *this << shift;
```

the template assignment operator will be chosen, which makes only the lower uint64_t be assigned. You should change the first assignent operator's signature to

```
uint128_t& operator=(const uint128_t& rhs)
//                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: but the compiler will chose the uint28_t operator over the templated one

Comment: @calc: No, because `*this << shift` is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as follows:

The type of `UPPER` is a 64-bit integer. Also, you are attempting to shift the integer by 63-bits, and the 64th bit is a zero in your case. So you lose all 63-bits which are actually holding the number.

PS: You said you don't like using a debugger, but if you just used one, this would be really really easy to figure out on your own.